# Java generics NullPointerException

Tags: java, generics, nullpointerexception

I want to make an Universal stack using generics .

```
public class UniversalStack<E> implements StackInterface<E> {

    private E[] stack;
    private int dim;
    private int index;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public UniversalStack(int dim)
    {
        this.dim=dim;
        this.index=0;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E[] stack = (E[]) new Object[dim];


    }

    @Override
    public void push(E el) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(index+1<dim)
        {
            stack[index] = el;
            index=index+1;
        }

    }
}
```

Everything compiles succesfully . The problem comes when I call the following :

```
UniversalStack<Integer> integerStack = new UniversalStack<>(10);
integerStack.push(new Integer(1));
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.java.lab4.UniversalStack.push(UniversalStack.java:41)
    at com.java.lab4.testStack.main(testStack.java:14)
```

Could you explain me what am I doing wrong ? If I made a stupid mistake don't be harsh on me , I am a beginner so I don't really know much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're re-declaring `stack` within your constructor rather than assigning to the outer `stack`:

```
E[] stack = (E[]) new Object[dim];
```

Should be

```
stack = (E[]) new Object[dim];
```

therefore `stack` is null when used in `push`.

Comment: Yeah , that was it .. I didn't realize I re-declared the stack member until I read it again after I posted here . Thanks !

Comment: I think eclipse tried to warn you, but you added suppresswarnings annotation :-)

Answer (score -1):

Just use the stack class that already exists for Java.

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
```

More documentation is here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: I'm confused, why does this warrant a -1?  He's trying to use a stack, and I suggest he used the stack implementation that already exists?  Seems like a better idea to use what exists and is tried and true than write your own....